# ggplot2 create barplot with CIs with descriptive data (i.e., without raw data)

Tags: r, ggplot2

in the base version of R it is easy (but cumbersome) to create a plot with error bars based on the descriptive data. With ggplot2 I am struggling to do so and all the examples I have found are based on the raw data.
Specifically, how can I create a barplot with confidence intervals for a simple two-group design? M1 = 3, M2 = 4, SD1 = 1, SD2 = 1.2, n1 = 111, n2 = 222? I started off simply with

```
ggplot(aes(x=c(1:2), y=c(3, 4))) + geom_bar()
# or
ggplot(aes(y=c(3, 4))) + geom_bar()
```

but not even this seem to work to create a barplot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `ggplot2::stat_summary()`? You can let it take care of your mean and se calculations (it relies on `library(Hmisc)` for most of these summary functions, so look there for more help).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
    stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean) +
    stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se)
```

[image]

Adjust `width =` for skinnier bars or error bars.

You can also use a true confidence interval with `mean_cl_normal` or `mean_cl_boot` and for a better visualization of the data dispersion:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
    stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", fun.data = mean_cl_normal)
```

[image]

Edit:
If your want to recreate a published paper just roll your data into a data.frame first:

```
datf <- data.frame(
    group = c("1", "2"),
    means = c(3,4),
    sds = c(1,1.2),
    ns = c(111, 222)
    )

# add your CI calcs as column called upr and lwr
library(tidyverse)
datf <- datf %>% mutate(lwr = means - (qnorm(.975)*(sds/sqrt(ns))),
                        upr = means + (qnorm(.975)*(sds/sqrt(ns))))

ggplot(datf, aes(group, y = means, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) +
    geom_crossbar()
```

[image]

Or the traditional standard of columns with error bars if you must like this:

```
ggplot(datf, aes(group, y = means, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_errorbar()
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if I follow: The means, SDs, and sample sizes is all what I have got, not the raw data like in your example. Computing the CIs is easy 3 +/- qnorm(.975)*(SD1/sqrt(n1)), but I am not sure how to implement them in ggplot2 to get a barplot. I basically want to create a graph based on the descriptive statistics reported in a published paper.

Comment: Thank you Nate. This is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an error bar to whatever values you want. They have an aesthetic called `ymin` and `ymax` that you can set. Here I draw the bars +/- 1 standard devaiation from the mean

```
dd<-read.table(text="sample mean sd n
1 3 1 111
2 4 1.2 222", header=T)

ggplot(dd, aes(sample)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd))
```

[image]